# Remove punctuation items from end of string

Tags: python, string, punctuation

I have a seemingly simple problem, which I cannot seem to solve. Given a string containing a DOI, I need to remove the last character if it is a punctuation mark until the last character is letter or number.

For example, if the string was:

```
sampleDoi = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"
```

I want the following output:

```
"10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044"
```

ie. remove `.',`

I wrote the following script to do this:

```
invalidChars = set(string.punctuation.replace("_", ""))
a = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"
i = -1
for each in reversed(a):
    if any(char in invalidChars for char in each):
        a = a[:i]
        i = i - 1
    else:
        print (a)
        break
```

However, this produces `10.1097/JHM-D-18-00` but I would like it to produce `10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044`. Why is the `44` removed from the end?

Comment: `strip('.\',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
import string

invalidChars = set(string.punctuation.replace("_", ""))
a = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"
i = -1
for each in reversed(a):
    if any(char in invalidChars for char in each):
        a = a[:i]
        i = i # Well Really this line can just be removed all together.
    else:
        print (a)
        break
```

This gives the output you want, while keeping the original code mostly the same.

Answer (score 4):

The string function `rstrip()` is designed to do *exactly* this:

```
>>> sampleDoi = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"
>>> sampleDoi.rstrip(",.'")
'10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044'
```

Comment: This is not a *general* solution though.

Comment: In what sense is it not general?

Comment: This certainly works for this example. But see OP says - " I need to remove the last character if it is a punctuation mark until the last character is letter or number." So any punctuations at the end should ideally be removed.

Comment: Wouldn't `sampleDoi.rstrip(string.punctuation)` work?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE That seems perfect here, since it handles every punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using `next` and [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) with a generator expression utilizing `enumerate` / `reversed`.

```
sampleDoi = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"

idx = next((i for i, j in enumerate(reversed(sampleDoi)) if j.isalnum()), 0)

res = sampleDoi[:-idx]

print(res)
'10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044'
```

The default parameter `0`is used so that, if no alphanumeric character is found, an empty string is returned.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont wanna use regex:

```
the_str = "10.1097/JHM-D-18-00044.',"
while the_str[-1] in string.punctuation:
    the_str = the_str[:-1]
```

Removes the last character until it's no longer a punctuation character.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question, since user doesn't know in advance that the last character(s) are invalid.

Comment: Why I agree there are better ways to do this, if the last character *isn't* invalid, the while loop will never run, so it will still give correct output.